# Convolution intuition: clarifying Terence Tao's "blurring"/"fuzz" interpretation

Tags: analysis, intuition, convolution

On this math.MO post, ["What is convolution intuitively?"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5892/what-is-convolution-intuitively),
Terence Tao's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/5916/36614) (in the case where one function is a bump function) involves "blurring" and "fuzz."

Could someone clarify his interpretation more explicitly? The intuition still escapes me. Thanks!

Comment: Have you already seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Derivations ? There you can find some animations which might be helpful for understanding.

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, I've stared at those animated gifs before, and I sort of understand the "sliding area" interpretation. How does it relate to Tao's fuzz interpretation?

Comment: If you want to blur a digital image (represented as an $m \times n$ matrix $A$), you can do that by convolving $A$ with a Gaussian blurring kernel $B$.  You could try it in Matlab and look at the results.  And you could compute the convolution by hand.  You'll see how the blurring happens -- each pixel in the convolution is just a weighted sum of nearby pixels in the original image.

Comment: What exactly confuses you about this answer?  I doubt I can write a better explanation than Terrance Tao of his own mathematical intuition, so if you want something clarified, you have to be specific.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I was looking for a something more concrete like Ruslan's answer below. What still eludes me though is his statement about convolution being the "fuzzy version of addition." I see that a bump function will "blur" another function everywhere, but what is the addition that Tao mentions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider a function $f_1$:
$$f_1(x)=\delta(x)$$
where $\delta(x)$ is Dirac delta, and a Gaussian function $g(x)$:
$$g(x)=\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right).$$
One of main properties of Dirac delta is this:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty q(x)\delta(x-x_0)dx=q(x_0).\tag1$$
Thus, convolution of $f_1$ and $g$ will equal $g$. Let's see how it looks ($f_1$ is red, $f_1*g$ is blue):

[image: $f_1$ is red, $f_1*g$ is blue]

You can see the 'blurring' effect of gaussian convolved with a Dirac delta.
Now consider more complex function:
$$f_2(x)=\sum_{i=-N}^N a(x_i) f_1(x-x_i)\Delta x_i.\tag2$$
$\Delta x_i$ here is step in $x$, i.e. $\Delta x_i=x_i-x_{i-1}$. We'll need it later. We'll take $\Delta x_i=\Delta x_j\; \forall x,j\in\mathbb{Z}$, then it can be viewed as just a coefficient before sum.

Here's a plot of $f_2$ and $f_2*g$ ($f_2$ is red, $f_2*g$ is blue):
[image: $f_2$ is red, $f_2*g$ is blue]

Here you can also see that the result of convolving a gaussian with a sum of Dirac deltas gives you blurred version of original function.
It's easy to generalize $f_2$ to a sum of infinite number of deltas with $N\to\infty$:
$$f_{2a}(x)=\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty a(x_i)f_1(x-x_i)\Delta x_i.$$

$f_{2a}(x)$ resembles a Riemann sum. Let's use this and take the limit $\Delta x_i\to0$:
$$f_3(x)=\lim_{\Delta x_i\to 0}f_{2a}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty a(t)f_1(x-t)dt\equiv\int_{-\infty}^\infty a(t)\delta(x-t)dt.\tag3$$
From $(1)$,
$$f_3(x)=a(x).$$
In $(3)$ after taking limit $x_i$ becomes $t$, and $\Delta x_i$ becomes $dt$. $\Delta x_i$ is needed to gradually attenuate Dirac delta amplitude as $\Delta x_i\to 0$, so that in the limit it becomes finite, resulting in a finite function.

Here's a plot of $f_3$ and $f_3*g$ ($f_3$ is red, $f_3*g$ is blue):

[image: $f_3$ is red, $f_3*g$ is blue]

This is finally the convolution of a usual function with a gaussian, which still does resemble the blurring, but is somewhat less obvious.

Also note that since $p*q=q*p$, you could as well start from a Dirac delta, represent $g(x)$ as a sum of scaled&translated $\delta(x)$'s and get the same result by summing $a(x)$'s scaled by $g(x_i)$ instead of $g(x)$'s scaled by $a(x_i)$.

Comment: The pictures help a lot, but the equations $f_2$ and $f_3$ confuse me more. I see that $f_2$ is just the sum of Dirac delta functions translated by $x_i$ and scaled by constants $a_i$, but what is $\Delta x_i$? In $f_3$, what is the function $a(x)$? And why did you choose to make $f_3(x)$ look like another convolution, even before convolving with $g(x)$?

Comment: Thanks Ruslan, that clarifies a lot! One more question: what do you mean by "normal"/"usual" function? Are you saying that any function can be written in the form $f_3$?

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it a bit more consistent. So I think I'll remove my previous comments (if you agree). As for your question about "normal" function, I'd say yes, any function can be represented in this form because of $(1)$. But I might be beaten by someone who suggests a pathological case for which $(1)$ is untrue :)

Comment: looks good to me!

Answer (score 5):

I'll just answer [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450147/convolution-intuition-clarifying-terence-taos-blurring-fuzz-interpretation#comment968605_450147), since the rest seems to have been addressed satisfactorily.

First we need to understand the statement "functions are fuzzy versions of points". What this is saying is that the *support* of a function is not a single point, but many. Consider $f$ being a [distribution of compact support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29), which we write $f\in \mathcal{E}'$ (if you are not familiar with distribution theory, just think locally integrable functions with compact support for now). Since the coordinate projections $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto x_i$ are $C^\infty$ functions, we have that the pairing 
$$ \langle f,x_i\rangle \tag{CoM}$$
is well defined. (In terms of locally integrable functions, think of equation (CoM) as $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x_i f(x) \mathrm{d}x$. Since $f$ has compact support the integral converges.)

This allows as to define the center-of-mass for each $f\in \mathcal{E}'$. That is, let $\mu: \mathcal{E}' \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the mapping 
$$ \mu(f) = \frac{1}{\langle f,1\rangle} \left( \langle f,x_1\rangle, \langle f,x_2\rangle,\ldots,\langle f,x_n\rangle\right)$$

Quite obviously $\mu$ is not injective: multiple functions/distributions can have the same center of mass. It is in this sense that functions are "fuzzy versions" of points: think of $f\in \mathcal{E}'$ with mass $\langle f,1\rangle = 1$ as something that is like the point $\mu(f)$, but spread out a bit in space.

Now let $f,g\in \mathcal{E}'$. Their convolution is well-defined. (See the Wikipedia link above.) We have the characterisation that for any smooth function $\phi$ the convolution satisfies
$$ \langle f*g,\phi\rangle = \langle f,\psi\rangle $$
where
$$ \psi(y) = \langle g,\tau_{-y} \phi\rangle $$
In terms of integrable functions this just says that
$$ f*g(x) = \int f(x-y)g(y) \mathrm{d}y $$
the usual definition.

Now, a direct computation shows that 
$$ \mu(f*g) = \mu(f) + \mu(g) $$
This you can easily check using the integrable functions definition also:
$$ \int x_i f*g(x) \mathrm{d}x = \iint x_i f(x-y) g(y) \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x = \iint (z_i + y_i) f(z) g(y) \mathrm{d}z \mathrm{d}y = \int g(y) \mathrm{d}y \int f(z)z_i \mathrm{d}z + \int f(z) \mathrm{d}z \int y_i g(y) \mathrm{d}y $$

That is to say: when you convolve two functions/distributions, you add their center of mass. So if you treat $f\in \mathcal{E}'$ as fuzzy versions of points, the convolution is their natural law of "vector addition".

Lastly know that the Dirac delta function $\delta_x\in \mathcal{E}'$. They correspond to the actual sharp (non-fuzzy) points!

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation! The distribution theory bits escaped me, so thank you for including the integrable functions interpretation as well. A few more questions: 1) I think I get the "adding centers of mass" idea. Is there a way to describe the shape of the convolution in terms of the fuzz of $f$ and $g$? 2) I'm guessing that the mass is preserved, in that $\langle f*g,1\rangle=1$. Is this true?

Comment: (1) Yes, the [support set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28mathematics%29) of $f*g$ will be a subset of the [Minkowski sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of their supports. When $f$ and $g$ are both non-negative, the two will in fact be equal. (When the functions are indefinitely-signed, there can be occasional cancellations.) (2) I am not sure what you mean by preservation of mass. Are you assuming that $\langle f,1\rangle = \langle g,1\rangle = 1$? In which case yes, whenever interchanging order of integration is allowed.

Comment: In general one expects (when one can interchange order of integration; see Fubini's theorem for example) that $$\int f*g(x) \mathrm{d}x = \iint f(x-y) g(y) \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x = \int f(z) \mathrm{d}z \cdot \int g(y) \mathrm{d}y $$